# Cannot encode a null value through CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes for a GET request

Tags: ios

```
        CFStringRef encodedValue = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                           value,
                                                                           NULL,
                                                                           (CFStringRef)@":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

The format of my request parameters in the input file:
    "request-params":[
        {
            "webLoginId":"2597171",
            "webGroupId":"null",
            "email":"swathi.chukkala@google.com",
            "emailOrder":"true",
            "emailQuote":"true"
        }
    ],
The null value is not getting encoded to form a URL to initiate a GET request. How do I encode  null value for a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Before formatting the request check with this condition :

```
-(NSString*)emptyStr:(NSString*)txt
{
    if (txt) return txt;
    else return @"";
}

NSString *webGroupId = nil;

NSString *checkStr = [self emptyStr:webGroupId];

NSLog(@"String is %@",checkStr);
```

Which returns only the Empty String.

Comment: I forgot to mention the @ in the email is getting converted to %40. I am trying the above suggestion though.

Comment: i guess @ is one of the Reserved characters after percent-encoding.Will it give problems in forming the url for a GET request?

Comment: no probelm, you can go ahead. while encoding the @ character it will be %40 then we can decode it.